# new File("some_path").exists() return false in some android devices

Tags: android

Recently I found that `new File("some_path").exists()` return `false` in some devices. I'm using Sony and Redmi devices for testing. In Sony device file exists condition return true. But redmi device returns false even the file is exist.

```
if(new File(locFilePath).exists()) {
     isFilePresent = true;
}else {
     isFilePresent = false;
}
```

Using above condition to check. File is saved here `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/app_package/files/offline/20170530164137.753`

Traced the log didn't find any exception related to this operation.

**Update**

on Redmi device downloading file contain `.midownload` extension along with file name. After successful download `.midownload` removed.

Help me to fix this.

Comment: how do you know the file exists?

Comment: How are you generating locFilePath?  Are you hard coding a path assuming external files are at a certain path?

Comment: have you given read wrire permission in androidManifest.xml ?
because in redmi its checking every time for Permission.

Comment: @pskink Manually I visited the path using file explorer

Comment: @GabeSechan the logic is i'm downloading file using download manager by specifying internal/external path, finally getting this path from download manager cursor.

Comment: @AniruddhParihar yes defined both permission in AndroidManifest

Comment: @pskink `c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_ID)), new String[]{c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME)), statusString}`

this what i'm using get path in a case; if file not present then i'm constructing file path using this `new File (getExternalFilesDir() + File.separator + "offline" + File.separator +"20170530164137.753")`

Comment: @pskink tried not working :(

Comment: No `COLUMN_LOCAL_URI` & `COLU‌​MN_LOCAL_FILENAME` both returns same value, but the `File("path").exist()` return `false`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145530/discussion-between-khaleel-jageer-and-pskink).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a hard coded file path it can vary between devices

Instead

```
new  File(locFilePath)
```

Try:

```
 new File (getExternalFilesDir() + File.separator + "offline" + File.separator +"20170530164137.753")
```

Comment: No not getFilesDir(). OP used getExternalFilesDir() as you can see.